# First subquery in the where clausule returns?

Tags: jquery, mysql, sql

the following Music Library DB:

[image]

And the following query:

```
SELECT CDNumber

FROM CD

WHERE CDNumber NOT IN

(SELECT T2.CDNumber

 FROM Track AS T1 JOIN Singer AS S1 ON T1.PerformanceCode = S1.PerformanceCode

 JOIN Singer AS S2 ON T1.PerformanceCode = S2.PerformanceCode

 WHERE S1.SingerName <> S2.SingerName)

 AND CDNumber IN

 (SELECT T2.CDNumber

  FROM Track AS T2 JOIN Recording AS R ON T2.PerformanceCode = R.Performance

  WHERE R.Year < CD.Year

  GROUP BY CDNumber

  HAVING count(*) >= 3)
```

Question: Does the first subquery in the where clause return the numbers of CDs where all the songs are by a single singer?(YES/NO) And how do I know that?

Answer (score 0):

yes, because...

```
    WHERE S1.SingerName <> S2.SingerName
```

single singer will not ever have 2 different singer name